# Different ways of ordering tasks

Tags: c#, async-await

For instance, I wanna order 3 tasks, which are depending in a clear order.
Is option B equal to option A concerning the continuation?

Option A:

```
Task returnTask = initTask.ContinueWith( async delegate { await homeTask; } ).ContinueWith( async delegate { await sessionTask; } );
await returnTask;
```

Option B - within 1 method:

```
await initTask;
await homeTask;
await sessionTask;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ContinueWith` has no special support for Task-returning delegates option A will not wait for tasks 2 and 3.

Are you aware that await does not start or run a task? It waits for an already running task. For that reason option B does not sequence the tasks either. It's almost the same as `await Task.WhenAll(...);`

Probably, you should use this:

```
await F1();
await F2();
await F3();
```

That way the next task is started after the previous one completed.